# Getting back to the first-time phone transfer wizard without factory resetting

Tags: file-transfer, data-transfer

During the first-time setup process, Android asks to connect my new phone to my old phone with a USB cable. I'm not ready to transfer yet but I want to test drive the phone. Is there a way to get back to that transfer wizard?